# Pivot table order

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pivot-table

I have sorted my data frame based on date and then pivot the dataframe, but the pivoted dataframe is not in the order I asked before. It has Dates not in the order.

```
df1= df1.sort_values(by=['DATE'])

df2=df1.pivot(index='CLIENT', columns=('VISIT_N'), values='DATE')
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Pandas questions are easlier if you can include a [reproducible sample of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Anobody knows what should be done?